# Python: почему print() не выводит данные типа float?

Tags: python, float, print

Даже на что-то совсем примитивное:

```
x = float(input())
y = float(input())
print(x + y)
```

Вводится:

```
0.1
0.2
```

Полный текст ошибки:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-2f0827b6674c> in <module>
      1 x = float(input())
      2 y = float(input())
----> 3 print(x + y)

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: Представленный код работает и в консоли, и в notebook. Может Вы что-то не то вводите в input?

Comment: Всё работает. Какой версии python? Лучше перезапустите заново блокнот и перепроверьте код.

Comment: Версия Питона 3.8.5

Comment: На такое полезно написать просто print без скобок и посмотреть, что выведет.

Answer (score 2):

Полагаю, что такая ошибка возможна только в одном случае - если вы где-то выше по коду случайно что-то присвоили переменной `print`:

```
print = 0.5 # что-то подобное где-то у вас есть
...
x = float(input())
y = float(input())
print(x + y)
```

Вывод:

```
0.1
0.2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-091b284b5278> in <module>()
      3 x = float(input())
      4 y = float(input())
----> 5 print(x + y)

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Починить это просто: **Среда выполнения** -> **Перезапустить среду выполнения**. И потом ещё раз выполните ячейку с вашим небольшим кодом, она должна успешно отработать. А вообще поищите поиском по коду других ячеек - где вы переопределяете `print`.